# How "NextStartDate" field value get calculated for DatedConversionRate object

Tags: apex, apexrest, multi-currency, currency, currencyisocode

I would like to know how the calculation is happening for DatedConversionRate's nextstartdate, is it depends on some configuration setting?

[image: DatedConversionRate object details for nextstartdate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value is simply whatever the next DatedExchangeRate's StartDate is.

For example, if you insert first record with a StartDate for `2020-01-01`, then you insert another record for the StartDate `2021-01-01`, the NextStartDate for `2020-01-01` will be set to `2021-01-01`.

If you later add a record with a StartDate of `2020-06-01`, then the NextStartDate for `2020-01-01` will change to `2020-06-01`, and the NextStartDate on `2020-06-01` will be `2021-01-01`.

This is all done by the server, so you don't need to worry about managing this.

Comment: Thank you Boss :) , got confused before , now its clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of Advanced Currency Management, where you can set exchange rates for a particular time period.

Help docs are here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=administration_about_advanced_currency_management.htm&type=5

It includes a link to more detailed information on dated exchange rates.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your reply. 

I have gone to provide link but not able to find out how the end date which is nextstartdate is getting populated.

 In my org I am seeing the behavior where for some record same day date is getting populated and for some record next year date is getting populated.

I am confused how the nextstartdate is getting populated.